# iBATIS and dblink?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ibatis, dblink

I am using PostgreSQL, and I use the dblink feature to update data on remote database. My project using iBATIS to work with database.

I need to run the query statement with parameter but the problem is the db_link require SQL to be enclosed in quote. And iBATIS do not understand it..

I have iBATIS sql:

```
    SELECT
    dblink_exec(
      'host=192.168.1.1 port=5432 user=abc dbname=wms password=abc',
      'UPDATE m_user_profile 
        first_name = #4#,
        last_name = #5# ,
        mobile_no = #6#
    WHERE user_id = CAST(#3# AS numeric)'
   );
```

But due to sql is enclosed in quote, the iBATIS can not find parameter to replace.

Is any solution for me to do it?

Comment: Use a foreign data wrapper and a foreign table. Then iBATIS won't be able to distinguish a local table from a remote table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, but I have not understand it, could you send an example?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would format help? Smth like:

```
SELECT
    dblink_exec(
      'host=192.168.20.60 port=5432 user=clk dbname=clkdb_wms password=clk',
      format('UPDATE m_user_profile 
        first_name = %L,
        last_name = %L ,
        mobile_no = %s
    WHERE user_id = CAST(%s AS numeric)',#4#,#5#,#6#,#3#)
   );
```